# Две facebook-like кнопки на странице

Tags: yii, facebook-api

[image]

Использую Yii. В `main.php` прописала все og мета-теги, подстроенные для "нравится сайт". При переходе на страницу описания приложения, я с помощью `Document.getElementById().setAttribute` изменяю данные тегов (ну, поэксперементировала). 
[link](http://mobile.crystalspring.kz/appstan/index.php/appsinfo/14)

Но что одна "нравится", что вторая "нравится" реагируют на описание сайта. Как вообще правильно это сделать?

Код первой кнопки:

```
<div class="fb-like"
data-href="http://mobile.crystalspring.kz/appstan"
data-send="false"
data-layout="button_count"
data-width="450"
data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Код второй:

```
<div class="fb-like"
data-href="http://mobile.crystalspring.kz/appstan/index.php/appsinfo/<?php
echo $model->app_id; ?>"
data-send="false"
data-layout="button_count"
data-width="450"
data-show-faces="false"></div>
```